# Comparing strings from argv

Tags: python

Here is my Python2 script, `test.py`:

```
x = sys.argv[1]
y = 'foo'
print(x)
print(y)
print(x is y)
```

I then call my script with `python test.py 'foo'`. This prints out:

```
foo
foo
False
```

But both `x` and `y` appear to be the same value, 'foo'. So why is this equivalence test returning `False`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==`

`is` will return True if two variables point to the same object, `==` if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.